# GCS 'Storage Object Viewer' role cannot view objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-console

I am trying to give a user read access to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The user has the "Storage Object Viewer" role

[image: Role: Storage Object Viewer]

but the user cannot see the items in the bucket:

[image: Error message]

The project ID is valid and <del>according to the docs the "Storage Object Viewer" role includes the storage.buckets.list permission</del> (EDIT: This is incorrect, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles).

The user can access the bucket if I give him the "Storage Object Admin" role, but then he also has write access. How do I just grant read access?

Comment: You can only VIEW the object (data and metadata) but you haven't permission on the bucket to list the object. Add another role or create a custom role with the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles), `Storage Object Viewer` does not have `storage.buckets.list` permission! it only contains the following 4 permissions (see the screenshot).

[image]

This means that the `identity` that has this role can only list/view objects inside a bucket and will not be allowed to list buckets and/or view bucket details.

---

if you need the `identity` to also list/view buckets, there is another *predefined legacy role* that you can use, named `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader`. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles)

Comment: It seems that Google might be in the process of retiring `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader`, at least based on the fact that I can't find it to grant it any more. This leaves no good way to grant this permission, from what I can see, other than granting the `Viewer` basic role or creating a custom role.

Comment: I don't really understand why they're making it so hard. The use case is pretty common: Say you want to let people see buckets, and create/view objects in those buckets, but not grant delete permissions on those objects. Since you don't want to grant delete you shouldn't grant `Storage Admin` at the project level, but then how do you let people see buckets? The only option other than a custom role seems to be the `Viewer` basic role, but I'd like to move away from basic roles because they grant too many permissions.

Comment: @Stephen Hmm I am able to find the role and use it (just tried). anyways, custom role is the only other solution. maybe they will simplify things in future!